# SQL Server Snapshot Replication - Is there an option to clean up the snapshot folder after X amount of time?

Tags: sql-server, replication

We're running snapshots from a 2016 to a 2019 SQL Server.

I've looked through Microsoft's documentation and I'm not seeing a clear cut way to have this, and I'm not seeing any jobs on the Publisher/Subscriber that would run this sort of cleanup.

We recently had a drive fill up and I want to make sure to get this sorted out if it's a native feature of replication, otherwise I'm going to run a PowerShell script to take care of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, even after re-initializing the replication job with suggestions, the job would not clean up after itself. If anyone reads this and needs another solution, I ended up using PowerShell in a SQL Agent job to clean up the replication folder.

```
Remove-Item -Path "H:\ReplData\unc\<folder_name>\*" -Recurse
```

This will remove anything under the main replication folder.

Answer (score 0):

set the retention period on the publication
also see the link below ( this is the replication escalation engineers blog site - so a great resource ) for a slight gotcha.

https://repltalk.com/2010/07/14/snapshot-files-deleted-when-immediate_sync-ntrue-and-retention-0/